# spdlog for C++; what(): Failed opening file ~/logs/log.txt for writing: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, debian, spdlog

I am using spdlog to do some simple logging on a c++ program on a beaglebone, debian 10. I set up a rotating logger:

`auto logger = spdlog::rotating_logger_mt("runtime_log", "~/logs/log.txt", max_size, max_files);`

and this returns the error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of spdlog::spdlog_ex'
  what():  Failed opening file ~/logs/log.txt for writing: No such file or directory
Aborted
```

I have already ensured that the directory exists and have tried `chmod -R 776 ~/logs/`
so:

```
drwxrwxrw- 2 user group 4096 Oct 28 09:03 logs
-rwxrwxrw- 1 user group 0 Oct 28 09:03 runtime.log
```

When given the path `logs/log.txt`, it works. This puts the logfile in `~/project/build/logs`

I have also tried giving the full path `/home/user/logs/log.txt`. And that works fine.

Why would my program and spdlog not be able to access the directory at the path `~/logs/log.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~` is special character in Bash shell, shorthand for home directory. The C++ program doesn't know about the `~`. Usual way to get home directory would be to use `std::getenv` function like:

```
const char* home_dir = std::getenv("HOME");
auto log_path = std::string{home_dir} + "/logs/log.txt";
```

I suggest you also to make use of `<filesystem>` header as it has functions to check the existence of files and directories.